# Creating a camera preview inside Fragment

Tags: android

I've searched throughout internet all the day but I haven't found anything that can solve my problem: how could I get a camera preview while my application is running? I think it's nothing difficult but I'm a beginner and I really can't get to this point. The code I'm using is the following:

```
public class CameraConnectionFragment extends Fragment {
private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();
/**
* The camera preview size will be chosen to be the smallest frame by pixel  size capable of
* containing a DESIRED_SIZE x DESIRED_SIZE square.
*/
private static final int MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE = 320;

/**
* Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation.
*/
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
static {
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}



/**
* {@link android.view.TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several  lifecycle events on a
* {@link TextureView}.
*/

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_connection_fragment, container, false);
Button capture = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
Button preview = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


  public void onClick(View v) {

      //I WANT TO INSERT THE CODE FOR THE CAMERA PREVIEW HERE.

  }
});

  capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


      public void onClick(View v) {
          try {
              captureSession.capture(previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
          }
          catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
              LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
          }

      }
  });

return view;

}
```

the xml file camera_connection_fragment is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.tensorflow.demo.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.RecognitionScoreView
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.OverlayView
    android:id="@+id/debug_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:text="Capture" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:text="Preview" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="134dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to put the code for the camera preview inside the

```
preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View v) {

  //I WANT TO INSERT THE CODE FOR THE CAMERA PREVIEW HERE.

}
});
```

Do you have any idea on how I should accomplish that?

Comment: Are you using `camera2` to open the camera? I can't seem to understand. Where does 'captureSession` come from, it's an instance of which class?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's an instance of the class CameraCaptureSession which has also the method capture() which just take a picture and it works perfectly. Only that it takes a picture if I click the button capture but I don't see any preview of what I'm capturing, only the picture taken. That's why maybe a surfaceView could work but I don't really know how to start, I've tried many ways.

Comment: As I understood you are using `camera2`, take a look at [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) example, I believe you need the method `openCamera`.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the method openCamera() which is also in my code and is the same as the one in the code you gave me but without the
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      requestCameraPermission();
      return;
    }

I've put the openCamera() in the onClick event (which works fine) but when I press the button the application just take a picture, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: You have to have a CAMERA permission in order to access the camera, so you have to add those lines and add the permission to the manifest

Comment: I think that openCamera() is not for opening the camera and see a preview but just to prepare taking a picture, indeed it uses try acquiring, which takes a picture. What do you think?

Comment: I have a camera permission, indeed, if I don't add the check for the permission I get a warning but I have the permission cause I added in XML and accepted when installing the app

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's easier to post it as an answer. Starting from API 23 you need to ask for permissions during runtime. So if you are planning to target devices 23 and up you need to add the runtime permission check along with Manifest permissions.

As for the preview, you need to look the method `createCameraPreviewSession`, more precisely to `onConfigured` callback:

```
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
```

As you can see `mPreviewRequest` and `mPreviewRequestBuilder` are used to set up the preview.

**EDIT:**

So `Camera2BasicFragment` is simply a `Fragment` that hosts the `Surface` and the camera, so when you run the app you can see the preview directly. As I understand, what you want, is to have an entry screen before the preview.

To facilitate things, you can structure your app so that your `CameraConnectionFragment` can act as an entry screen (where you will have a button to start the preview), which will then lead to the preview fragment.

And the preview fragment will be `Camera2BasicFragment` which you can just copy from the repository. So in your `onClick` method, you will perform a fragment transaction that will lead you to `Camera2BasicFragment`.

Comment: I've tried to remove the capture part in the createCameraPreviewSession and put the method inside the onClick which responde to the touch of preview button but when I press the preview I don't get any preview, instead, it still takes picture when I click preview, I don't really get the point.

Comment: @mikepythonic You don't need to remove anything from `createCameraPreviewSession`, look at `onOpened` method, that's where the Preview is created. Try copying the three lines that you see in `onOpened` into your `onClick`.

Comment: I've already tried to do that, the problem is that when I call createCameraPreviewSession, I just run the code of that method  and it ends that I get a picture of what the camera is looking at, but the problem is that I don't see the camera preview. What I would like is that when I click preview button I see the camera preview and not the picture taken (which happens now). Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what

Comment: @mikepythonic let me clone this project from GitHub and get back to you

Comment: @mikepythonic I cloned the repository, check the edited answer.

Comment: The Fragment code I'm running where the onClick method is, is almost equal to the Camera2BasicFragment, the only main difference I did was to replace in CreateCameraPreviewSession the mcaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler); with mCaptureSession.Capture(mPreviewRequest,
mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler); which take only one picture and then nothing else. With the setRepeating request I get a camera preview but with the Capture method I don't: I only get the picture taken without any preview. If I call the Camera2Basic I get what I don't want

Comment: Is there any way to use a method such as SetRepeatingRequest (which give me the preview) without taking pictures?

Comment: @mikepythonic As I understand it's not `setRepeatingRequest` that gives the preview. Take a look at [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-least-you-can-do-with-camera2-api-2971c8c81b8b) tutorial, more precisely at methods `openCamera` and `setUpCamera`, these are responsible for preview.